# failed to get data from website. using web_scraper plugin flutter

Tags: flutter, web, twitter, inspect, web-inspector

I try to get data from twitter website. I have done research on the internet and how to get data from website using dart/flutter. So I have found a plugin called ***web_scraper*** but i cant understand how do this on by getting inspact of twitter site.

this is code i have tried

i add plugin to puspec.YAML like this

```
dependencies:
  web_scraper: ^0.1.4
```

then this is code:

```
final rawUrl = 'https://twitter.com/FlutterDev/status/1367166395235012608';
final webScraper = WebScraper('https://twitter.com');
final endpoint = rawUrl.replaceAll(r'https://twitter.com', '');
if (await webScraper.loadWebPage(endpoint)) {
  final titleElements = webScraper.getElement(

      // todo:I can't think how to find text for here ,

      []);

  print(titleElements);
}
```

this is tweet link:

https://twitter.com/FlutterDev/status/1367166395235012608

this is inspect of page

[image]

i want tweet title & tweet body only!

Answer (score -1):

The Web page of Twitter is highly dynamic so to get its page source is hard. The easy way is to get credentials to use its API [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply-for-access). You can use several functions available.

For your case, you could use this:

```
var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1367166395235012608?tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,created_at,entities,geo,id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,possibly_sensitive,referenced_tweets,source,text,withheld'));


http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

And you'd get something like this:

```
    {data: {attachments: {media_keys: [16_1367162250558013440]}, lang: en, entities: {hashtags: [{start: 32, end: 46, tag: 
....
, source: Twitter Web App, author_id: 420730316}}
```

More details [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9956214/T1LMiT5U#c936778b-e343-4a23-b1b4-433c501cf6eb).